# After comparing the array data of the request data and the array data of the response data through the lambda expression, add the list

Tags: c#, lambda

I am making an api server

The client sends the request data like this

```
 {
  "classCode": "01",
   "array": [
   {
    "GroupID": "Class",
    "CodeID": "A",
    "Value": "1"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": "Class",
    "CodeID": "B",
    "Value": "1"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": "Class",
    "CodeID": "C",
    "Value": "1"
  },
  {
    "ClassID": "Class",
    "CodeID": "D",
    "Value": "1"
  }
 ]
}
```

The api server being created receives the requested data in this way and sends the response data.

```
public List<user_model> List(Dictionary<string, object> param)
{
       .. code omission
       
        List<user_model> tempList = new List<user_model>();

        List<user_model> resultList = new List<user_model>();
        
        jsonReq.Session = param;
        
        .. code omission
}
```

First, the received data is stored in the templist

```
{
  "Code": "00",
  "Msg": "SUCCESS",
  "Data": [
{
  "className": "aClass",
  "array": [
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
        "CodeID": "A",
        "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "B",
       "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "C",
       "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "D",
       "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "E",
       "Value": "1"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "className": "bClass",
  "array": [
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
        "CodeID": "A",
        "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "B",
       "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "C",
       "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "D",
       "Value": "0"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "E",
       "Value": "1"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "className": "cClass",
  "array": [
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
        "CodeID": "A",
        "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "B",
       "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "C",
       "Value": "1"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "D",
       "Value": "0"
    },
    {
       "GroupID": "Class",
       "CodeID": "E",
       "Value": "0"
     }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I am going to filter and put only the data containing "aClass" back in the resultList

I want to express it in a lambda expression, but I get an error in the code I wrote.

```
resultList .AddRange(tempList .Where(um => 
um.array[0].Value.Equals(param["array"].ToString()) && 
um.array[1].Value.Equals(param["array"].ToString())  && 
um.array[2].Value.Equals(param["array"].ToString()) && 
um.array[3].Value.Equals(param["array"].ToString())));
```

How can I modify the lambda expression to insert the desired value?

Comment: You say "I get an error in the code I wrote" - could you give more details about that?

Comment: Please provide the user_model class as well as the code the populates tempList.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you generated tempList from the recievedData its going to be hard to debug - but two places to look for would be:

- Comparing a single value in the array with the entire param["array"] object
- Indexing 4 times into the tempList array which might only have 3 values

I assume its the former - perhaps you wanted something like:

```
var arrayArray = ((IEnumerable)param["array"]).ToArray();
resultList.AddRange(tempList.Where(um => 
um.array[0].Value.Equals(arrayArray[0].ToString()) && 
um.array[1].Value.Equals(arrayArray[1].ToString()) && 
um.array[2].Value.Equals(arrayArray[2].ToString()) && 
um.array[3].Value.Equals(arrayArray[3].ToString())));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't quite understand. How should I make the code?

Comment: My bad, I've updated my response - This is assuming the contents of the passed in "param" ... Without seeing all the code its a guess

Comment: Thank you for answer



By the way 



'var arrayArray = (IEnumerable(param["array"])).ToArray();'



I get an error here




var arrayArray = ((IEnumerable)(param["array"]));



If I convert it like this, there is no error




resultList.AddRange(tempList.Where(um =>
um.array[0].Value.Equals(arrayArray[0].ToString()) &&
um.array[1].Value.Equals(arrayArray[1].ToString()) &&
um.array[2].Value.Equals(arrayArray[2].ToString()) &&
um.array[3].Value.Equals(arrayArray[3].ToString())));




I get an error What should I do?

Comment: I've ammended my answer again, I got a little confused by your response.. It definitely still needs a ToArray() or a ToList() in order for you to index into it